# How to Bind a DropDownList Text Value to another DropDownList using Kendo UI for MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC and need to bind the selected value of a dropdown list to another dropdownlist.  I want the user to only be shown the citiy entries that are applicable to the State selection they choose.    My dropdownlist is as follows:

```
<div id="bindcity" class="inr_div" data-bind="visible: showFromChooseCity">
  <h5 class="inr_hd">City<span>*</span>:</h5>
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("fromCity")
    .DataTextField("name")
    .DataValueField("id")
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
      source.Read(read =>
      {
        read.Action("GetCity", "Quote");
      })
      .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .SelectedIndex(0)
  )
```

I setup several controller classes as follows:

```
    public JsonResult GetZips()
    {
        FreightEntities freight = new FreightEntities();
        var zips = freight.ZipCodes.AsQueryable();
        var city = freight.ZipCodes.AsQueryable();
        if (city != null)
        {
            zips = zips.Where(z => z.Zip = zips);
        }
        return Json(freight.ZipCodes.Select(z => new {Zip = z.Zip}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetCity()
    {
        FreightEntities freight = new FreightEntities();
        var state = freight.ZipCodes.AsQueryable();
        var city = freight.ZipCodes.AsQueryable();
        if (state != null)
        {
            city = city.Where(s => s.State = state);
        }
        return Json(freight.ZipCodes.Select(s => new { State = s.State }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    public JsonResult GetState()
    {
        FreightEntities freight = new FreightEntities();
        return Json(freight.ZipCodes.Select(s => new {State = s.State }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The above code now gives the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<FRCV2.Models.ZipCode>' to 'string'
```

Since I'm not using an ID field in my entities, what's the appropriate way of comparing the fields above?
How do I achieve this cascading dropdownlist effect?

Comment: You would need to use javascrpt/jquery to handle to change event of the dropdown (but what is the point of adding the same value to 2 different controls?)

Comment: So, is it better to forego the separate read only inputs and just go with the dropdown lists?

Comment: The dropdown will post back the selected value, so not sure why you also need the readonly input?

Comment: Hmm, now your asking an entirely different question. An example of creating Kendo cascading dropdown lists is [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist)